# Submitted url has crawl issue for deleted page

Tags: wordpress

I have deleted some pages earlier from my wordpress site. But GSC showing error"submitted url has crawl issue" for those deleted pages. After using inspecting url tool, it showing url is not on Google.
How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have two choices:

1. 301 Redirect
2. 410 Gone Redirect

> 301 Redirect

This 301 redirect response notifies the search engines that the page has moved permanently from the old URL to the new URL. The search engines also transfer the old URL page rank to the new URL.

You can do this by **.htaccess**

```
Redirect 301 /old-page.html http://example.com/new-page.html
```

> 410 Gone Redirect

If a URL returns a 410, Google knows for sure you removed the URL on purpose and it should, therefore, remove that URL from its index much sooner.

You can do this by **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/expired_page$1 [R=410,L]
```